# Convenient way of checking equality for Optionals

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm looking for a more convenient way of proofing equality for an Optional value.

This is what an [Oracle Blog post](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) suggests:

```
Optional<USB> maybeUSB = ...;
maybeUSB.filter(usb -> "3.0".equals(usb.getVersion())
                    .ifPresent(() -> System.out.println("ok"));
```

IMHO results in something like

```
if (maybeUSB.filter(c -> "3.0".equals(c.getVersion())).isPresent()) {
   ...
}
```

Of course that's kind of a poor example because it compares the Version and not the instance of USB itself but I think it should still proof my point.

Is this really as good as it gets?

No

```
boolean presentAndEquals(Object)
```

or

```
boolean deepEquals(Object)
```

Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

I'm not that happy with Optionals.equals either.
Do I really have to box an Object first to instantly unbox and check for equality ?

**EDIT II:**

Pretty damn happy with:

```
optional
    .filter(nonOptional::equals)
    .isPresent()
```

nowadays.

After some years of functional programming, `if` looses a **lot** of relevance.

Comment: Don't optimise prematurely. You either have to box (which you don't know the cost of), or test for `isPresent()` (which you also don't know the cost of). `maybeFoo.equals(Optional.of(...))` is readable, so use it.

Comment: I agree about premature optimization, but it's more about code golf than timing.. talking about Java right ;)

Comment: "I'm not happy" There's nothing special about `Optional`: it's just a container for a reference. Would you expect another class which happened to contain a `String` to return true for `new Frobnitz("some string").equals("some string")`? The cases where the brevity is useful are outweighed by the cases where it's just plain incorrect.

Comment: The cleanest possible standard way of checking for equality, but you're not happy. Maybe you should switch to a different language.

Comment: If you look at the source code for `Optional`, it is really a bunch of convenience functions that look just as ugly. If this is something you do often, don't hesitate to start your own `name.ebner.franz.Optionals` and make the ugly go away.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have many options.

Already noted:

```
boolean isEqual = maybeFoo.equals(Optional.of(testFoo));
```

Alternatively:

```
boolean isEqual = maybeFoo.isPresent() && maybeFoo.get().equals(testFoo);
```

Or:

```
boolean isEqual = testFoo.equals(maybeFoo.orElse(null));
```

These last two do have slightly different semantics: each returns a different value when `maybeFoo` is empty and `testFoo` is null. It's not clear which is the correct response (which I guess is one reason there's not a standard API method that does this).

You can probably come up with others if you read the `Optional` API doc and apply some thought. There's nothing magic that's absent from the docs.

More generally, if you're knocking against this often enough for it to bother you, you might be approaching `Optional` with the wrong philosophy.

As I see it, `Optional` is about acknowledging that something won't always be present, and that you need (sometimes verbose) code to handle that.

This should be the exception. Wherever possible, try and create variables that **can't** be null or `Optional.empty()`.

In situations where this is unavoidable, embrace the fact that you need extra code.

Comment: Only the second solution fits the question -- the OP wants the test to be false if neither value is present.

Comment: It's not clear that OP has thought about what he really wants in that situation.

Comment: Maybe, but I thought the intent was made clear in the wish list example `boolean presentAndEquals(Object)`

Comment: Also note that null and 'not present' are not necessarily the same thing. Another part of the point of `Optional` is that it makes presence and absence explicit. `null` means whatever you want it to.

Comment: The last one will not return a different value when `testFoo` is `null`, it will throw a `NullPointerException`, just like the first one.

Comment: To me, the expression `maybeFoo.isPresent() && maybeFoo.get().equals(testFoo)` is the cleanest. But if you want to squeeze it to the shortest possible, you can use `maybeUSB.map(obj::equals).orElse(false)` (if `obj` is guaranteed to be non-`null`) or `maybeUSB.map(x->x.equals(obj)).orElse(false)`, respectively.

Comment: None of these options are satisfactory. `maybeFoo.equals(Optional.of(testFoo))` unnecessarily creates a new object. `maybeFoo.isPresent() && maybeFoo.get().equals(testFoo)` is semantically correct, but requires a separate variable; e.g. it wont work directly with an expensive method `findFoo()` that returns `Optional<Foo>`. And lastly `testFoo.equals(maybeFoo.orElse(null))` won't work if `testFoo` could possibly be `null`. Folks, we need an `Optional.isPresentAndEquals()` method in the core Java library.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this just seems like a glaring omission in Optional's API. Thanks for enumerating the options.

Answer (score 8):

`Optional` implements the `equals` method directly:

```
if (maybeUSB.equals(Optional.ofNullable(testUSB))) {
    ...
}
```

(you can also use `Objects.equals` rather than calling `equals` directly)

EDIT:

If you want both not present to be false, you can do this:

```
if (maybeUSB.equals(Optional.ofNullable(testUSB)) && maybeUSB.isPresent()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the result to be false if both are not present.

Comment: edited - you can just put in an extra clause to check value presence

Comment: @HankD The value to compare to is, well, a value. So the situation "both are not present." simply doesn't occur. As to your other comment: `presentAndEquals` means that a value is present and equal to another value.

Answer (score 6):

Would this work?

```
if (maybeUSB.map(c -> c.getVersion().equals("3.0")).orElse(false))
```

Comment: That's clever (but still readable), I like it!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to check equality of Optional by it's existed method `equals`.
It compares two Optional by it's inner values.

```
package java.util;
public final class Optional<T> {
...
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
...
        return obj instanceof Optional<?> other
                && Objects.equals(value, other.value);
```