# How to check if an optional value is present and equal to another value

Tags: java, option-type

Is there a way to express the below conditional in a more concise fashion?

```java
    Optional<Order> order = getOrder(); // API Call
    if (
      order.getCustomer().isPresent() &&
      order.getCustomer().get().equals(INTERNAL_CUSTOMER)
    ) {
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004579/convenient-way-of-checking-equality-for-optionals

Comment: Would you see `if (INTERNAL_CUSTOMER.equals(order.getCustomer().orElse(null))) { ... }` as "more concise" (I wouldn't say it necessarily _is_)?

Comment: if order.isEmpty() then order.getCustomer() will fail

Comment: `order.getCustomer()` won't even compile. You probably want `if (INTERNAL_CUSTOMER.equals(order.map(Order::getCustomer).orElse(null))) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the lambda expression using `map` and `filter`.
`map` is used to `pull/manipulae` actual data coming from stream and `filter` will be used for `predicating` the value if it's true or false, `isPresent` will return true if `stream` returned any result after `filter`

`if (order.map(Order::getCustomer).filter(INTERNAL_CUSTOMER::equals).isPresent()) { ... }`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.